# Proc means on all columns in sas

Tags: sas, mean

I have a huge table with a lot of columns. 
I have numeric columns and character columns.
I need the sum of each numeric column and the max of each character column.
I need this row in a new DB

Is there a way to do it without write all varaible names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, PROC MEANS will analyse all numeric variables if you leave out the VAR statement.

```
PROC MEANS data = work.example SUM;
RUN;
```

As far as I know, if you try to include character variables in a PROC MEANS it will not execute (see [here](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi27/p018-27.pdf)).

If it's numeric values in character variables you're looking to retrieve the MAX of, perhaps consider using an [INPUT function](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000180357.htm) to convert them to numeric variables.

Comment: Thanks for your suggesting. Is there a way to write a VAR statement that select only my numeric columns?

Comment: As mentioned, if you do not include the VAR statement it will automatically select all numeric columns.

Comment: If you really really want a VAR statement, you could use VAR _ Numeric _ ;  (without spaces between the underscore and the word numeric)